# Python code launched by udev rule fails to copy files and fails silently

Tags: python, shell, raspberry-pi, udev

I am developing a simple application on a Raspberry Pi to auto configure the WiFi by reading a configuration file from a USB.  To test the concept I created a simple udev rule that calls the following script on usb "Add".  This code is based on a stack overflow question of a few years ago.

```
#!/bin/sh
logger -s "Running autoconfigure."

# Run Python code
sudo -H -u pi sh -c "nohup /usr/bin/python /home/pi/datalogger/autocopy.py &"

ret=$?
if [ $ret -ne 0 ]; then
    logger -s "Returned error: $ret"
fi
exit
```

and the Python code is:

```
# Raspberry Pi autocopy scripts to copy a File from USB to /home/pi on USB insert
# Requires udev rule:
# KERNEL=="sd*1", ACTION=="add", RUN=="/home/pi/datalogger/autocopy.sh"
# or similar

import shutil
import syslog
import sys

f= open("/home/pi/datalogger/temp.txt","w+")
for i in range(10):
     f.write("This is line %d\r\n" % (i+1))
f.close()

source="/home/pi/datalogger/temp.txt"
destination="/home/pi/datalogger/test.txt"

syslog.syslog(sys.version)

try:
   shutil.copyfile(source, destination)
except shutil.Error as e:
   syslog.syslog(e)
   exit(1)
except shutil.IOError as e:
   syslog.syslog(e)
   exit(1)
except:
    syslog.syslog(sys.exc_info())
    exit(1)

syslog.syslog("Completed normally")
exit(0)
```

All this code does is create and copy a file as triggered by USB key insertion (the rest can come later).  The issue is that the files don't create or copy and the scripts don't error (although they do run).  The Python code does return a "1" code indicating there may be an error.  If I run manually as the pi user - the scripts work perfectly as they do if I run as the sudo user.  I have relaxed all permissions as part of testing. I am really not sure where to look?  There is noting in the logs that indicates that there is a problem with the code.  Any advice / guidance appreciated.

Comment: maybe system runs it as different user, with different privileges, in different folder, with different environment's variables, without access to screen. You could try to write in folder `/var` or `/tmp` it should be avaliable for any user.

Comment: That's a good idea - will try later today, however I set everything to 777 (just for testing!) to try to cover off on permission issues

Comment: You are using `nohup`, have you checked the content of `nohup.out`?

Comment: nohup.out is empty.

Comment: @skyman: Append this `...autocopy.py &" >/tmp/autocopy 2>&1` and check the contents of `/tmp/autocopy` afterwards. Try this also while removed **all** `try: ... except...` and replacing all `.syslog(...` with `print(...)`.